# Scroll to Top of Page onClick with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that is rendered with a static ID called `#mainView`. I have a component that renders a `button` element lower in the page, and I want to scroll up to the `#mainView` element when the button is clicked. As far as I can tell, this is a very simple user experience that has been apart of the web standard for [decades now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) and can be accomplished with a simple `<a href="#mainView">...</a>` in vanilla HTML (and extended with `scroll-behavior: smooth` as an experimental feature).

I have spent the last hour trying to replicate this behavior in React, to no avail. Hashes in URLs are ignored, and Gatsby complains about an external link. I have tried `@reach/router/navigate` and `Link`. I have tried to use `onClick={...}`, and manually trying to override `onclick` does not work. None of these produce *any* behavior at all and the only approaches I can find on SO involve extending `React.Component` and getting inside `render()`, using another method, using refs, and all sorts of stuff that should 10,000% not be necessary for such simple UX.

Is there *any* way to get React to *easily* replicate what I want here? And, why might the React developers actively *break* traditional web functionality? All responses appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I found the solution myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Gatsby, and the solution was to import `gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll` package and add to plugins ([docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll/#examples-of-usage)), then navigate with:

```
<button onClick={() => scrollTo('#mainView')}>My link</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the beautiful way to do it, but you can try using `element.scrollIntoView`, in the example I'm using the id and `document.getElementById` but you can replace it with `ref`

```js
const Element = ({id,text})=>(<div id={id} style={{width:"100%", height: "400px", border:"solid 1px black"}} >{text}</div>);

const Scroll = ({to})=><span onClick={()=>document.getElementById(to).scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"})} >Scroll</span>

const App = ()=><div>
<h1>MyApp</h1>
<Element id="el-1" text="Lorem Ipsum" />
<Element id="el-2" text="Lorem Ipsum" />
<Element id="el-3" text="Lorem Ipsum" />
<Scroll to="el-2"/>
</div>



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

And yes, if it's not to a element, but to the top `window.scrollTo({top:0,behavior:'smooth'})` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Scroll extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef1 = React.createRef();
    this.myRef2 = React.createRef();
    this.myRef3 = React.createRef();
    this.myRef4 = React.createRef();
  }
  scrollSmooth(e, scroll) {
    if (scroll === "sec1") {
      this.myRef1.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start"
      });
    } else if (scroll === "sec2") {
      this.myRef2.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start"
      });
    } else if (scroll === "sec3") {
      this.myRef3.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start"
      });
    } else if (scroll === "sec4") {
      this.myRef4.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start"
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <ul className="list-group">
          <li className="list" onClick={e => this.scrollSmooth(e, "sec1")}>
            section1
          </li>
          <li className="list" onClick={e => this.scrollSmooth(e, "sec2")}>
            section2
          </li>
          <li className="list" onClick={e => this.scrollSmooth(e, "sec3")}>
            section3
          </li>
          <li className="list" onClick={e => this.scrollSmooth(e, "sec4")}>
            section4
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="section1" ref={this.myRef1}>
            <p>Section 1</p>
          </div>
          <div className="section2" ref={this.myRef2}>
            <p>Section 2</p>
          </div>
          <div className="section3" ref={this.myRef3}>
            <p>Section 3</p>
          </div>
          <div className="section4" ref={this.myRef4}>
            <p>Section 4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Scroll;
```

Hi refer this component. 
Working link [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-turing-15hgh?file=/src/App.js:51-1935)